# Values of variables in scope when using closure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures

Can you explain the difference between these 3 pieces of code? They seems identical to me, but the output are different.

1:

```
var i;

function print(){return function(){console.log(b)}};

function doSetTimeout(b){setTimeout(print(),2000);};

for(i=0;i<10;i++){doSetTimeout(i)}
```

2:

```
var i;

function print(){console.log(b)};

function doSetTimeout(b){setTimeout(print,2000);};

for(i=0;i<10;i++){doSetTimeout(i)}
```

3:

```
var i;

function doSetTimeout(b){setTimeout(function(){console.log(b)},2000);};

for(i=0;i<10;i++){doSetTimeout(i)}
```

The first 2 are returning b as undefined, while the 3rd is returning the expected value.

Comment: btw, no need for colon after block statements, like `{};`

Comment: in 1 and 2, you're not passing `b` into the print function

Comment: you could move `print` inside of `doSetTimeout`, then `b` is a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first two examples you gave, you aren't passing b into print(), so print has no way to find that variable by looking at its lexical parents.

The closure isn't going to occur when you pass the function value, with print as a parameter, it's going to happen wherever setTimeout() is defined and print() is actually invoked. So you're not getting access to the context you think you are.

In the last example it works anyway, because you are *defining* the anonymous function inside of a function being executed that already knows what b is, so b is available.

"When a given execution context encounters a function definition in the code, a new function object is created with an internal property named [[scope]] (as in lexical scope) which references the current VariableEnvironment. (ES 5 13.0-2)

Every function gets a [[scope]] property, and when the function is invoked the value of the scope property is assigned to the outer lexical environment reference (or outerLex) property of its VariableEnvironment. (ES 5 10.4.3.5-7) In this way, each VariableEnvironment inherits from the VariableEnvironment of its lexical parent. This scope chaining runs the length of the lexical hierarchy starting from the global object."

Source:

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/understanding-javascript-closures/

Also a good read:

http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/